# D3 Map - Marks Zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have a problem with marks on my D3 map. When I set up zooming for each state the marks are not zooming within the map..

That's my first try for D3 map, so sorry if I messed up something in the code. If I did or missed something I'll really appreciate explanation.
If anyone can help with that I'll be really thankful.

[image]
[image]

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    centered;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1070)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", clicked);

var g = svg.append("g");

var div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

d3.json("https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  g.append("g")
      .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("fill", "#26404b")
      .on("click", clicked);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("id", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path);

  // CITIES
  d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Miserlou/c5cd8364bf9b2420bb29/raw/2bf258763cdddd704f8ffd3ea9a3e81d25e2c6f6/cities.json", function(data) {
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1];
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        if(d.population >= 1 && d.population < 10000){
          return 1;
        }
        else if(d.population >= 10000 && d.population < 100000){
          return 2;
        }
        else if(d.population >= 100000 && d.population < 500000){
          return 3;
        }
        else if(d.population >= 500000 && d.population < 1000000){
          return 4;
        }
        else if(d.population >= 1000000 && d.population < 5000000){
          return 5;
        }
        else if(d.population < 5000000){
          return 10;
        }
        else {
          return 0;
        };
      })
        .style("fill", "rgba(26, 188, 156,0.8)")  

        // HOVER
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style('fill', 'rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.3)')
            .style('stroke', '#1abc9c')
            .style('stroke-width', 4);      
            div.transition()        
                 .duration(200)      
                 .style("opacity", .9);      
                 div.html('<span id="place">City: ' + d.city + '</span><br><span id="people">Calls: ' + d.population + '</span>')
                 .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + 35 + "px")     
                 .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
        })   
          .on("mouseout", function(d) { 
            d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style('fill', 'rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.8)')
            .style('stroke-width', 0);        
              div.transition()        
                 .duration(200)      
                 .style("opacity", 0);   
          });
    }); 
});

function clicked(d) {
  var x, y, k;

  if (d && centered !== d) {
    var centroid = path.centroid(d);
    x = centroid[0];
    y = centroid[1];
    k = 4;
    centered = d;
  } else {
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    k = 1;
    centered = null;
  }

  g.selectAll("path")
      .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d === centered; });

  g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
}
```

```css
.background {
  fill: #435863;
  pointer-events: all;
}

path:hover {
  fill-opacity: .9;
}

#states .active {
  fill-opacity: .9;
}

#state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(22, 160, 133, .1);
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

/* Style for Custom Tooltip */
div.tooltip {   
  position: absolute;             
  height: 28px;                 
  padding: 5px 10px;              
  font: 12px sans-serif;        
  background: white;   
  border: 0px;      
  border-radius: 5px;           
  pointer-events: none;         
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are appending your circles to the `svg` directly, but your US state are being appended to a `g` element. Your zoom transition is only applied to the `g`, meaning the circles will be unaffected:

```
g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
```

You should be able to correct this by simply appending your circles to the same `g` element itself, rather than the `svg`:

```
  d3.json("cities.json", function(data) {
    g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      ...
```

Comment: Ooooh.. thanks a lot, I was struggling with that for a few hrs.. haha

Comment: I've been there, nothing more frustrating than losing your mind, unleashing a torrent of expletives, and gesturing angrily at the screen for the sake of one or two characters.